# How can i Solve the below issue

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am executing this query and I am getting this error even though I am selecting the database and executing the error.
here is the code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STUDENT;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CAMPUS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SEMESTER;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ROOM;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GRADES;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COURSE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INSTRUCTOR;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLASS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STUDENT_GRADE;
```

CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
STUDENT_ID   INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Last_Name    VARCHAR(30),
First_Name   VARCHAR(30),
Address      VARCHAR(40),
ZIP          VARCHAR(10),
MAJOR        VARCHAR(20),
CLASS       int(2),
STATUS       VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Morote','Italo','P.O. Box 619, 5808 Semper St.','32828','MATHEMATICS',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Martin','Yacky','313-6948 Nunc, Ave','36702','SPANISH',3,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Yostin','Duglas','Ap #593-8291 Id St.','26151','BUSINESS',1,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Dasti','Cosimel','328-4572 Elit Rd.','95886','SPANISH',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Dixon','Steve','Ap #547-7314 Feugiat. Street','42756','PHIL',1,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Alfaro','Patricia','P.O. Box 977, 6922 Sed Street','52838','ENGLISH',1,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Farruco','Rose','Ap #179-4485 Lectus Road','10816','ENGLISH',3,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Pope','Vector','Ap #878-2252 Curabitur Av.','53175','PHYSICS',3,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Los','Angeles','Ap #552-758 Convallis St.','56968','FINANCE',3,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Diaz','Cameron','Ap #145-1961 Sed Street','63397','BUSINESS',3,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Gonzalez','Andew','Ap #141-9425 In Road','87521','BUSINESS',4,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Michael','Jordan','Ap #412-5802 Venenatis Rd.','77696','MARKETING',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Chelerson','Scholy','911-8666 A Rd.','32829','CIS',2,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Payton','Tanya','5759 Nec, Street','23461','SPANISH',3,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Jorge','Michael','Ap #642-7393 Ut, Ave','33186','PHIL',1,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Cretiza','Noitus','8659 Arcu. Avenue','91267','PHYSICS',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Delami','Oscar','3512 Pellentesque. St.','33481','MATHEMATICS',4,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Francisco','Zoeter','285-9157 Proin Road','98674','CS',1,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Cohen','Aurora','P.O. Box 957, 9450 Arcu Street','30350','PHIL',3,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Black','Joshua','3655 Sed St.','95684','FRENCH',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Barber','Michael','875-9349 Magnis St.','66498','PSY',4,'SATISFACTORY');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Preston','Inez','Ap #829-845 Nisi Av.','27404','PSY',1,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Direz','Blaster','439-1369 Cursus Av.','60644','MARKETING',2,'FAILING');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (Last_Name, First_Name, Address, ZIP, MAJOR, CLASS, STATUS)
VALUES('Aiton','Valeria','7513 Vitae Street','61245','MARKETING',2,'FAILING');

CREATE TABLE CAMPUS
(
CAMPUS_NAME  VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
Address      VARCHAR(40),
ZIP          VARCHAR(10),
PHONE_NO     VARCHAR(20),
UNIQUE(CAMPUS_NAME),
PRIMARY KEY(CAMPUS_NAME));

INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('New York Campus','405-6298 In Street','62840','1-639-674-3520');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Chicago','820-7808 Risus, Rd.','51852','1-824-430-8362');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('San Francisco Campus','505-182 Luctus, Ave','21345','1-460-439-2331');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Seattle Campus','P.O. Box 215, 1469 Eu Rd.','52681','1-448-789-7971');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Washington Campus','631-5139 Leo. St.','29402','1-282-625-5720');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Los Angeles Campus','6161 Nostra, Road','83643','1-547-459-9473');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Denver Campus','9309 Cras Road','23421','1-680-673-7298');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Austin Campus','P.O. Box 878, 7621 Donec Road','73261','1-755-573-0468');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Houston Campus','P.O. Box 406, 9600 Odio Ave','32802','1-721-423-4315');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Detroit Campus','7574 Semper St.','21211','1-583-233-9026');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('San Diego Campus','6939 Ligula. St.','75022','1-941-394-7241');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('San Antonio Campus','7422 Vel Avenue','63763','1-604-359-7505');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Memphis Campus','P.O. Box 328, 5280 Donec Rd.','75068','1-865-208-5487');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Portland Campus','788-7924 Tellus. Street','75088','1-260-552-0600');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Miami Campus','518-7627 Ac Avenue','89090','1-262-155-0231');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Phoenix Campus','921-4825 Nullam Rd.','23117','1-324-211-7180');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Dallas Campus','Ap #202-6418 Eleifend Ave','54674','1-663-374-3235');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Atlanta Campus','927-3569 Id Road','71661','1-315-710-9509');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('San Jose Campus','8637 Ullamcorper Rd.','10001','1-224-161-4524');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Las Vegas Campus','P.O. Box 169, 7139 Arcu Rd.','83588','1-789-125-9687');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Indianapolis Campus','744-3904 Vulputate, Road','37762','1-640-455-9785');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Baltimore Campus','2849 At Ave','40882','1-299-696-4483');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Cleveland Campus','P.O. Box 785, 7330 Urna. St.','55794','1-789-114-1794');
INSERT INTO CAMPUS (CAMPUS_NAME, Address, ZIP, PHONE_NO)
VALUES('Oklahoma Campus','172-3924 At Ave','31619','1-111-206-2900');

CREATE TABLE SEMESTER
(
SEMESTER_NAME ENUM('FALL', 'SPRING', 'SUMMER'));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ROOM CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE ROOM
(
Campus_Name  VARCHAR(45),
ROOM_NO      VARCHAR(10),
FACILITY     VARCHAR(45),
CAPACITY     int(3)
);

INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('New York Campus','6','Lloydminster',30);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Chicago','19','Erode',32);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('San Francisco Campus','40','Cantalupo in Sabina',38);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Seattle','40','Assiniboia',25);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Washington Campus','23','Kessenich',42);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Los Angeles Campus','47','Stony Plain',46);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Denver Campus','29','Ulm',44);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Austin Campus','46','Bielefeld',39);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Houston Campus','37','Georgia',38);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Detroit Campus','29','Lummen',30);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('San Diego Campus','3','Pak Pattan',33);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('San Antonio Campus','37','South Perth',27);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Memphis Campus','35','Meeuwen',14);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Portland Campus','20','Belcarra',23);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Miami Campus','5','Jette',27);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Phoenix Campus','24','Milwaukee',18);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Dallas Campus','23','Afsnee',39);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('San Jose Campus','50','Stamford',26);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Atlanta Campus','5','Stamford',21);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Las Vegas Campus','40','Morgex',11);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Indianapolis Campus','1','Montague',21);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Baltimore Campus','40','Cumberland',21);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Cleveland Campus','4','Harrison Hot Springs',32);
INSERT INTO ROOM(Campus_Name,ROOM_NO,FACILITY,CAPACITY)
VALUES('Oklahoma Campus','10','Sainte-Ode',15);

CREATE TABLE GRADES
(
Grade ENUM('A','B','C','D','F','I','W')
);

CREATE TABLE COURSE
(
Course_No    Varchar(10)  NOT NULL,
Course_Name  Varchar(25),
CreditHours  int(2),
UNIQUE(COURSE_NO),
PRIMARY KEY(COURSE_NO)
);

INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1043','TECH121',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1006','Psy101',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1696','Psy101',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1291','HUM234',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1841','Psy101',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1697','ELE102',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1292','LIT405',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1698','ELE101',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1255','Math101',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1842','TECH121',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1010','Psy101',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1810','Psy101',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1044','Math131',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1293','Math131',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1528','CS234',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1324','PHY345',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1045','Math101',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1659','CS211',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1294','PHY345',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1144','Psy101',2);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1843','ELE102',1);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1569','Math101',3);
INSERT INTO COURSE(Course_No,Course_Name,CreditHours)
VALUES('1811','ENG304',3);

CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR
(
INSTRUCTOR_ID VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME     VARCHAR(30),
FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR(20),
ADDRESS       VARCHAR(40),
ZIP           VARCHAR(10),
OFFICE_NO     VARCHAR(10),
UNIQUE(INSTRUCTOR_ID),
PRIMARY KEY(INSTRUCTOR_ID)
);

INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('400','Thane','Puckett','P.O. Box 895, 191 Erat Rd.','53841','30');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('737','Jared','Tate','Ap #177-1334 Faucibus St.','88675','21');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('640','Yuli','Hurst','Ap #799-5088 Scelerisque St.','26162','12');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('256','Micah','Pace','P.O. Box 638, 2109 Adipiscing Rd.','40665','12');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('741','Kasper','Duran','565-193 Nunc Avenue','55756','17');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('653','Dolan','Moore','3869 Cursus Road','37236','10');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('688','Ciaran','Blackwell','Ap #754-6723 Faucibus Rd.','83479','17');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('940','Kennedy','Fowler','749-1142 Non Av.','98172','22');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('499','Devin','Acosta','7613 Vel Road','93686','19');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('280','Driscoll','Justice','P.O. Box 113, 3705 Ut, St.','69877','23');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('937',',Cairo','Donaldson','6470 Adipiscing Rd.','63032','26');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('415','Hammett','Glenn','262-2645 At Rd.','84839','22');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('549','Elliott','Donaldson','5470 Dolor. Street','62489','23');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('639','Lamar','Robles','5719 Consectetuer St.','20213','25');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('767','Colin','Riley','P.O. Box 114, 1663 Ultrices. Street','23254','16');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('344','Richard','Thornton','P.O. Box 931, 8187 Lacinia. St.','29349','23');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('581','Raymond','Snow','1032 Est St.','66699','20');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('474','Nero','Rhodes','6050 Ante Ave','37967','28');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('534','Tate','Carr','P.O. Box 213, 1879 Purus. Ave','19803','15');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('521','Lance','Waters','656-7361 Conubia Ave','6315','26');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('413','Abbot','Ross','P.O. Box 859, 9379 Sed Avenue','45051','25');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('891','Dylan','Forbes','225-3164 Fermentum Ave','65642','26');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('879','Arsenio','Singleton','505-6318 Vel, St.','97288','10');
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ADDRESS,ZIP,OFFICE_NO)
VALUES('350','Thor','Copeland','Ap #816-3443 Magna. Avenue','43447','4');

CREATE TABLE APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR
(
Instructor_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Course_No     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('400','1044');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('737','1528');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('640','1324');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('256','1842');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('741','1006');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('653','1431');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('688','1291');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('940','1810');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('499','1841');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('280','1211');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('937','1144');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('415','1255');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('549','1033');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('639','1881');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('767','1526');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('344','1249');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('581','1659');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('474','1298');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('534','1569');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('521','1192');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('413','1722');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('891','1511');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('879','1696');
INSERT INTO APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR(Instructor_ID, Course_No)
VALUES('350','1844');

Create TABLE CLASS
(
Class_id      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Course_No     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Section       VARCHAR(10),
Semester      Varchar(15),
Year          VARCHAR(4),
Instructor_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Campus        Varchar(15),
Room_No       VARCHAR(10),
Start_Date    Date,
Start_Time    Time,
UNIQUE (CLass_id),
PRIMARY KEY (Class_id)
);

INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('12408','1044','Fall','499','2014-10-08','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('15716','1006','Other','639','2014-10-08','8:00','17','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('12525','1291',' Other','767','2014-10-08','8:00','18','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('16500','1696','Winter','937','2015-01-03','8:00','19','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('19047','1291','Winter','280','2015-01-03','8:00','14','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('12587','1841','Other','280','2014-08-10','8:00','15','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('17106','1696','Other','400','2014-08-10','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('14331','1291','Other','413','2014-08-10','8:00','14','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('17246','1696','Summer','640','2015-06-12','8:00','12','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('17092','1255','Summer','639','2015-06-12','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('14169','1842','Fall','344','2014-08-10','8:00','13','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('13062','1006','Winter','879','2015-01-03','8:00','12','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('17267','1810','Summer','640','2015-06-12','8:00','15','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('15415','1044','Summer','549','2015-06-12','8:00','15','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('11386','1291','Fall','767','2014-08-10','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('14972','1528','Other','937','2014-08-10','8:00','17','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('15009','1324','Fall','256','2014-08-10','8:00','11','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('18265','1044','Winter','415','2015-01-03','8:00','12','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('16415','1659','Fall','474','2014-08-10','8:00','14','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('19464','1291','Fall','521','2014-08-10','8:00','18','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('12433','1144','Summer','415','2015-06-12','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('19175','1842','Winter','534','2015-01-03','8:00','10','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('19864','1569','Summer','280','2015-06-12','8:00','14','2014');
INSERT INTO CLASS(Class_ID,Course_No,Semester,Instructor_ID,Start_Date,Start_Time,Section,Year)
VALUES('17022','1810','Other','940','2014-08-10','8:00','15','2014');

CREATE TABLE STUDENT_GRADE
(
Student_ID    MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Class_ID      VARCHAR(10),
Student_Grade ENUM('A','B','C','D','F','I','W'),
PRIMARY KEY(Student_ID)
);

Commit;

SHOW TABLES;

This is the error message I am getting
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STUDENT   Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the database you're using with;

```
  USE db_name;
```

Comment: Where do I need to mention the USE db_name in the code

Comment: To access a specific database, type the following command at the mysql> prompt, replacing dbname with the name of the database that you want to access. Make sure you do not forget the semicolon at the end of the statement. After you access a database, you can run SQL queries, list tables, and so on.